# Git tracking remote repo

Tags: git, github, branch

First off, we are just moving to GIT and I don't know how to accomplish my goal.

I have a project CORE that needs to be split off for a client as the client wants a CUSTOM project. **Mostly** only the view will be different in CUSTOM from that in CORE, but we need all bug fixes that go into CORE to be reflected or merged into CUSTOM.

I know about GIT --tracking, but I think that is only for branches correct?

We need to have both CORE and CUSTOM hosted on Github, so I am not allowed to just have CUSTOM be a branch on my local machine.

Anyone? Anyone?

Comment: You can have a git "folder" be home to multiple remote repositories and you can compare branches between them. Check out `git remote add` and related topics.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, CUSTOM should be a long term `support branch` of your project. What you need is acctually a git workflow. Check [gitflow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) which introduced an execllant branch model and provided an experimental sub-command `git flow support` which is just for your case, see the last entry of this [FAQ](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/wiki/FAQ).

If you intend to keep CUSTOM as a seperate repo on github, you could have you `origin` remote point to the core repo, and `CUSTOM`remote point to the CUSTOM repo. Then, set the branch `master` to track master of orgin and branch `branch-custom` tracking master of CUSTOM remote.

Here is the code:

```
git remote add -t master origin <path to orgin>
git remote add -t branch-custom CUSTOM <path to CUSTOM>
```